# How to perform actions based on App's state?

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application that must do some action based on the app's current state.

For eg.: I will compare my requirement with WhatsApp

- When the user's chat window is open it just gives a small sound and shows the message.
- When the app is running (in UI sense, the user is doing something in the app), the app is just sending a sound and updates the list view accordingly.
- When the app is neither running in the background nor in the memory ,  it is sending push notifications

What are the methods that need to override for this functionality?

Should these methods be implemented in all the activity's of the app or in a single activity?

Though my question can be summarized as [User Session Maintanence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399598/how-to-store-user-state-in-android-in-my-case). None of the questions are similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you want notifications to show then you should carry out all your notification tasks in Background Service. Take a look at this https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/send-request.html
and this https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

And if you want some actions on some states of an app then

```
public class MainActivity{

public static boolean appUI;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
appUI = true;
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
appUI = false;
}
}
```

You can override such methods as above, you can learn to use such methods here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle